# Find maximum value of an attribute in a array of objects

Tags: java, max

In a Java program, I have a class WaterBody in which one of the attributes is a double for electric power output. How can I find the maximum electric power output value in an array of `WaterBody` instances?

Here's my prototype:

```
public static WaterBody mostPowerful(WaterBody[] waterBodies) {

}
```

Attribute is `electricPower` and I have the getter method `getElectricPower`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection, java.util.Comparator)

Comment: Homework? Declare a variable `maxval` to store the object with the maximum value, iterate over the array with foreach, call `getElectricPower()` on each object and compare its value with the value from the object in your variable. If it is greater it is your new maximum object (assign it to `maxval`). Try to code it yourself, it can be fun! Show your code if it doesn't work out immediately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid you'll have to do a linear search:

```
public static WaterBody mostPowerful(WaterBody[] waterBodies) {
    double maxValue = -1;
    int indexOfMaxValue = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < waterBodies.length; i++) {
        if(waterBodies[i].getElectricPower() > maxValue) {
            indexOfMaxValue = i;
        }
    }
    return waterBodies[indexOfMaxValue];
}
```

A more elegant solution can be achieved by using a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). It defines an Interface, which tells if one object is "bigger" or "smaller" than another. You can define a `Comparator` like that:

```
Comparator<String> cmp = new Comparator<WaterBody>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(WaterBody o1, WaterBody o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1.getElectricPower(), o2.getElectricPower());
    }
};
```

If you'll need do operations like these often, it is advised to have a collection which always keeps it's content sorted, like a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)
It would be a lot smarter to use a collection, which keeps it's content sorted.

```
TreeSet<WaterBody> waterBodiesTree = new TreeSet<>(cmp);
Collections.addAll(waterBodiesTree, waterBodies);
WaterBody smallest = waterBodiesTree.first();
WaterBody biggest = waterBodiesTree.last();
```

If you only need to sort your array, the first example I used turns into a one-liner (using the same `Comparator` as defined earlier):

```
public static WaterBody mostPowerful(WaterBody[] waterBodies) {
    return Collections.max(waterbodies, cmp);
}
```

Comment: Manual searching is not necessary. You can use `Collections.max` as suggested by Steve Kuo, or in Java 8, use `Arrays.stream` to convert the array into a stream, then call `Stream.max`.

Comment: Apart from the typo on "waterbodies" on the if statement, that does the trick. Will look about collections though. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young I will add it to my post, but keep in mind that knowing how to do the very basics (like finding the maximum in a list) should come before learning how to let everything be handled by built in code. At university we learned to do these things the hard way first and I guess for a good reason. But I'll add it to the answer for curious readers

Comment: @Neuron On the contrary, in professional code (which I always assume questions on SO are about, unless the OP says otherwise) it's important to use library code rather than reinventing the wheel. :-)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young I guess I pretty much overachieved all needs now :P

Comment: @Neuron I've just added a Java 8 solution. Between your answer and mine, I think we have all bases covered. :-P

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Java 8, you can write this as a one-liner:

```
public static WaterBody mostPowerful(WaterBody[] waterBodies) {
    return Arrays.stream(waterBodies)
            .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(WaterBody::getElectricPower))
            .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
}
```

The `orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new)` causes a `NoSuchElementException` to be thrown if the incoming array is empty (and thus there is no maximum value). If you want to return null instead, use `orElse(null)`.

Comment: uh, look at that fancy stream ;) definitely the nicest solution if performance is not a big issue!

Comment: @Neuron To test your claim of "if performance is not a big issue", I decided to write [a little program](https://gist.github.com/cky/ac45ccc5e1548b86075e) to test the various solution approaches. There are some surprising results in there....

Comment: On my computer, from fastest to slowest: nullable (2.4 ms), collections (3.1 ms), stream (4.6 ms), optional double (5.7 ms), optional (15.8 ms). The optional double and optional results actually surprised me a lot.

Comment: Worst-case (elements in ascending order) performance on my computer: nullable (2.2 ms), collections (3.2 ms), stream (4.6 ms), optional double (8.5 ms), optional (17.6 ms). This appreciably slowed down the optional double and optional results!

Answer (score 3):

You can define a comparator in the `WaterBody` class

```
class WaterBody {
  :
  public static final Comparator<WaterBody> POWER_COMPARATOR =
    new Comparator<WaterBody>() {
      public int compare(WaterBody dev1, WaterBody dev2) {
        return Double.compare(dev1.getPower(), dev2.getPower());
      }
  };  
}
```

and use it as below

```
 WaterBody device = Collections.max(devices, WaterBody.POWER_COMPARATOR);
```

Comment: `Double.compare(dev1.getElectricPower(), dev2.getElectricPower())` is still a more elegant solution. Not only is it easier to read, it also doesn't create two new objects for the stack.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, included.