# How to find the object with the highest value of an attribute?

Tags: java, oop

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Book crimeAndPunishment = new Book();
crimeAndPunishment.name = "Crime and Punishment";
crimeAndPunishment.author = "Fyodor Dostoevsky";
crimeAndPunishment.numberOfPages = 600;

Book meditations = new Book();
meditations.name = "Meditations on first philosophy";
meditations.author = "René Descartes";
meditations.numberOfPages = 300;

Book languageInstinct = new Book();
languageInstinct.name = "The Language Instinct";
languageInstinct.author = "Steven Pinker";
languageInstinct.numberOfPages = 400;
```

Hi, I'm new to java and I've created a few book objects but need to find the book with the most pages. I have looked up how to use for loops and while loops but I'm not sure what condition should be set.

Comment: Add them to a list or an array and then see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/35281335/5292302

Comment: @Basil OP wants the object not the max value, I suggest you change dup to my link or something better

Comment: @PetterFriberg Can you use the “Edit” button to add your link as a second original item? The Stack Overflow user interface for iPhone is currently broken, and won’t physically let me use that Edit feature.

Comment: @BasilBourque sorry I have no gold in Java, anyway np if question survives these comments are enough